# Bitsadmin Download Error

Tags: command-line, download, batch-file

I saw a feed referring to downloading via bitsadmin (v.7.5.7601.17514) on Windows 7.

I have trouble implementing this myself and continue to get errors when running the code when running from a batch file(which is my requirement)

Errorcode: 0x80190194
Error Context: 0x00000005

The code is as follows:

```
bitsadmin.exe /Transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal https://sites.com/sites/Shared%%20Documents/Reporting/HP.zip C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\HP.zip
```

Can you seen anything that would hinder this code from running? The site is a sharepoint.

Comment: If would help if you said what the errors are ... please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/822409/edit) your question to include this information together with details of your operating system and the version of bitsadmin you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This [seems to correspond](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4222fb2c-640f-4460-9dd6-5f372f732163/content-download-stuck-bits-error-0x80190194?forum=configmanagerapps) to a HTTP 404 (File Not Found) status.

Try to replace `%%20` with `%20` in `https://sites.com/sites/Shared%%20Documents/Reporting/HP.zip`.